# what is the difference between loading dynamic library (which is internally calling COM dll) in main thread and worker thread?

Tags: com

Can any body tell me what is the difference between loading dynamic library (which is internally calling COM dll) in main thread and worker thread.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried? Have you seen any difference? What problem does it cause?

Comment: With Worker thread unable to Register the COM Dll

Comment: Throwing an exception like this "First-chance exception at 0x77125608 (KernelBase.dll) in LoadNativeDll.exe: 0x8001010E: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread."

Comment: Add referenced code, and exception in your question. Because now it's unclear

Comment: You need to call CoInitialize() in every thread that uses COM.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, due to the support of the application development language, there is little need for special on the main thread to use COM.
For example, check the OLE/COM option with the project creation wizard.
However, when using multiple worker threads and using COM in the worker thread, the following actions are necessary.

Worker threads using COM must initialize OLE at the beginning of the thread (before creating/using COM objects).
For Win32 API, it is [CoInitialize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543.aspx)/[CoInitializeEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279.aspx).
 Alternatively, depending on the application development language, there will be equivalent functions and libraries, so please call it.

Worker threads that use COM must perform their own message processing loop independently of Windows message processing loop performed by the main thread responsible for UI.

Please pay attention to the COM component being used.
If the value of [ThreadingModel in the registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682390.aspx) in which the COM component is registered is an empty string (nothing is set), an event may not be notified to the work thread and an exception may be raised.
If there is no value in this registry please write "Apartment".

Please use COM object basically only from the created thread.
If a COM object is called from another thread that is not the thread that created the COM object, an error may occur or normal operation may not be performed.

Additional notes:
In order to terminate the worker thread, it is necessary to perform the above cleaning up.
Terminate and release COM object, stop message processing loop, call [CoUnintialize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688715.aspx), and so on.
Resources created/allocated within the worker thread must be terminated/released.